# Does anybody know of a really good 3rd Party Treeview Control for C#

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I am involved in a project where I have the need for a really rich treeview control. The application is written using WinForms in C#. The treeview control in .net seems to be fairly limited. It is lacking in several ways:

- multiselection, can't select multiple nodes at the same time
- poor drag support for repositioning items
- Poor label editing support
- Poor support for control over how all the elements are drawn & custom painting(everything from the + next to the node, the little dots that make up the tree, icons and text)

I will likely end up having to write my own from scratch but before that happens I though I would check to see if any 3rd Parties have seen an opportunity here and beat me to it..

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/1) has great controls for winforms and wpf.  You can find information on their TreeView control here:

http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/treeview.aspx

[DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/) also makes great controls and I have used them in the past.  You can find more information on their TreeView control here:

http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Tree_List/index.xml?tab=features

Comment: Ah, Telerik, I should have known, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Developer Express](http://devexpress.com) has some excellent controls for WinForms, ASP.NET and WPF. I've been using their products since 2000, back when I was a Delphi developer.

Comment: thanks for the recomendation!

Answer (score 0):

Component Art Win.UI had a good treeview control.  Have a look here http://www.componentart.com/products/wpf/

Comment: This looks great, but not for winforms, just WPF. thanks though